# Why can't I access a file using GetExecutingAssembly.GetFile()?

Tags: c#, assemblies

This code is a simplified to aid my understanding. The actual code will be finding an xml file in a calling assembly. However, I can't even access an xml file in this simplified example. I have set the TestFile.xml as an Embedded Resource.
Any ideas why this code doesn't work?

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new A();
            test.TestGettingAssemblies();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    internal class A
    {
        internal void TestGettingAssemblies()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);
            Console.WriteLine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetFile("TestFile.xml") == null);
            Console.WriteLine(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykv4s.png), [Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiSSG.png)

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using(var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestFile.xml"))
using(TextReader tr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
      Console.WriteLine(tr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

For more information go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file).

It it does not work, I would recommend you to call `assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` and check if result contanins "TestFile.xml"

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get it with GetManifestResouceStream. It's weird that GetFile doesn't work.